# How to show validation message below horizontal radio buttons in Bootstrap 4.1.3?

Tags: html, css, validation, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show validation message below horizontally aligned radio buttons in Bootstrap 4.1.3. Below is the default render:

[image: Validation message next to horizontal radio buttons]

```
<hr>
<div class="">
  <div class="col-sm text-center">
    Please confirm that your eye color is:<br>
    <span class="response" id="eye_color"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm text-center">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="eye_color_yes" value="yes" name="eye_color" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="eye_color_yes">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="eye_color_no" value="no" name="eye_color" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="eye_color_no">No</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please select an option.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

I tried adding a break `<br>` and got this:

[image]

```
<hr>
<div class="">
  <div class="col-sm text-center">
    Please confirm that your eye color is:<br>
    <span class="response" id="eye_color"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm text-center">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="eye_color_yes" value="yes" name="eye_color" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="eye_color_yes">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="eye_color_no" value="no" name="eye_color" required>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="eye_color_no">No</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        <br>Please select an option.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

But what I would really like is for the validation message to appear directly under the two horizontal radio buttons. I am using [Bootstrap 4.1.3's validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#validation) for ease but for some reason can't figure this part out. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at your current html structure, your invalid feedback div is nested inside your second column div. Thus the result you see.

Comment: @I. R. R. Using Bootstrap 4.1.3's validation functionality requires that it be a part of the form-check form-check-inline div otherwise the validation message does not show.

Comment: It wouldn't matter because he's trying to validate what I assume are both radio buttons with one validation did. The only non-javascript way of doing it that I can think of requires some css hackery, and if he wants it too look good on all view breakpoints it might need even more lines of css.

Answer (score 5):

I was just struggling with the same thing. This answer is probably too late for you, but hopefully it helps someone else. The validation message is displaying where it is because Bootstrap adds `display: inline-flex;` on a parent element when displaying horizontal forms, preventing it from dropping down to the next line.

I was able to relocate the `invalid-feedback` validation message outside the flex layout element, and have it continue to react to the validation (without any extra javascript) by placing a dummy radio button with the same name before it and hiding it with CSS. A bit hacky, but it works.

```
<div class="col-sm text-center">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="eye_color_yes" value="yes" name="eye_color" required>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="eye_color_yes">Yes</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="eye_color_no" value="no" name="eye_color" required>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="eye_color_no">No</label>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="eye_color" style="display:none;" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please select an option.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Strange that Bootstrap doesn't provide a way to handle this out of the box. Oh well.

Comment: I could confirm that this 'hack' works on Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score -1):

I created a form only using Bootstrap 4 class. You can use this snippet for your desired result.

```html
<div class="container">
  <form >
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   Please confirm that your eye color is:
   </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="optradio" value="option1" checked>Blue
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="optradio" value="option2">Black
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input">Grey
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-danger">
     Please select color.
  </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

On the place of below code:

```
<div class="text-danger">
     Please select color.
  </div>
```

You can use below snippet it will look better for showing error messages:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Please select color.
  </div>
```

Comment: Your example isn't using Bootstraps validation tool nor is it using horizontal radio buttons. The validation tool executes on form submission checking all required form fields for an answer then gives the invalid-feedback if there is a required field with on answer. Good try though!